# Can pandas parse csv file with unknown number of comments, a header and line(s) to be skipped

Tags: pandas, csv, parsing, comments

I have a file that has an unknown number of comments, followed by a header, followed by a second row that has to do with data types but is really just junk to me.

```
# Comment Line 
# Another comment -- there could be lots
index value
not wanted
1 10
2 20
```

With a priori knowledge of the number of comments (which sort of violates the idea of comments) the file can be read by 
`pandas pd.read_csv(fname, header=0, comment='#', skiprows=[3])`

In my case, though, the number 3 is unknown. I only know the header is index 0 not counting comments and I know that the unwanted row is index 1 not counting comments. `header` works the way I want but not `skiprows`. Is there a way to make use of this information to read the file easily? By "easily", I mean something short of the following which opens the file, counts the preliminary comments, then reads:

```
ncomment = 0
crows = []
fname = "sample.csv"
with open(fname,"r") as f:
    while f.readline().startswith("#"):
        crows.append(ncomment)
        ncomment += 1
crows = crows + [ncomment+1]
data = pd.read_csv(fname,header=0,skiprows = crows, index_col=0,delim_whitespace = True)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can with `header` + `comment` to get a MultiIndex, then drop the unwanted level. `header` is evaluated after the comments are removed, so it's always `[0, 1]`.  (I'm using `delim_whitespace=True` because there aren't any `','`s in your sample data).

```
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', comment='#', header=[0, 1], delim_whitespace=True)
#  index  value
#    not wanted
#0     1     10
#1     2     20
```

We can drop in the same line:

```
df = (pd.read_csv('sample.csv', comment='#', header=[0, 1], delim_whitespace=True)
        .droplevel(1, axis=1))
#   index  value
#0      1     10
#1      2     20
```